# How to get the values from outside the braces using regex

Tags: java, javascript, regex

Please see the requirement below.

```
String s1 = "||||(;)||(;;)||(;)";
```

output from the  above string should be: `||||||`

```
String s2 = ";;(||)";
```

output from the  above string should be: `;;`

```
String s3 = ";;";
```

output from the above string should be: `;;`

I was trying below example, but the output is for the s1 is `;`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(^(.*?)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(filter);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only removing everything inside braces you can use:

```
str.replaceAll("\([^\)]*\)", "");
```

Comment: You beat me to it, +1. :)

Comment: didn't think about `replaceAll` :P.. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex ..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "||||(;)||(;;)||(;)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(?:\\(.*?\\))");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
case -1 : s1 = "||||(;)||(;;)||(;)";
||||
||
||

case -2 :   s1 = ";;(||)";

    ;;
```